# intellij not compiling all of my classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to intellij and trying to familiarize myself with it. So I checked out a project that I have on subversion, set up the compile output path. My problem is that when I click **Build**-> Build project/build module/rebuild module only part of the classes get compiled but when I go to the non compiled classes and right-click on each individually and select recompile the class get recompiled successfully. What am I missing here?

Comment: are you getting any error over there

Comment: The classes that are not being compiled have no errors.

Comment: No I am not using spring.

Comment: Then search for @Component scan or if not present add it and give the path of the outermost package which include all your code

Comment: @AmitGujarathi: Spring's `@ComponentScan` has _absolutely_ nothing to do with compiling java code

Comment: Use maven, it fixes all of these problems and is actually really easy

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am not sure how to simplify it. The issue is just that some classes are compiling and building automatically and some classes aren't although there are no errors.

Comment: Do they have the same icons in the project view? Maybe you've excluded them from compilation?